# Relating a sample mean to the population mean

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Theorem states that if samples derived from a population with normal distribution has a mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ Then $$Y'= \frac{1}{n}\sum Y_i$$

has mean $\mu$ where $Y_i$'s are random variables for each sample $i=(1,2,...,n)$

Okay, Are we assuming that $Y_i's$ have the same mean here? if $Y_i's$ have different means that what would be according mean of $Y'$

Comment: The $Y_i$'s are all i.i.d. samples from that normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. You may want to include what that "Theorem" states, and where it comes from.

Comment: @ClementC. i.i.d?

Comment: Independent and identically distributed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $Y_i$~$ N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ then $\displaystyle{E(Y')=E(\frac{\sum_iY_i}{n})=\frac{\sum_i\mu_i}{n}}$

The situation you describe is that all the $Y_i$s are sampled from the same population $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
So $\displaystyle{E(Y')=E(\frac{\sum_iY_i}{n})=\frac{\sum_i\mu}{n}=\mu}$.
(We did not need independence here).

The variance part requires independence of the $Y_i$s. So assuming they are i.i.d (independent, identically distributed), we get $\displaystyle{Var(Y')=Var(\frac{\sum_iY_i}{n})=\frac{\sum_iVar(Y_i)}{n^2}=\frac{\sum_i\sigma^2}{n^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}$

Comment: What can we say about $V(Y')$